# Why is @Transactional not rolling back saving an entity in this integration test?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-transactions

I have a controller that receives some form data, and is supposed to

- save some entities into a database
- save any images submitted into the file system

The controller is annotated with `@Transactional` (though I've read it's not a great idea to have this annotation on a controller level...) with `rollbackFor = Exception.class`, because if any exception occurs, I want to rollback changes made to any entities.

When I run the test and check that the entity I would expect to be gone is there or not, it's still there. So, `@Transactional` doesn't seem to be working as I intended it to.

ClassifiedController.java, in src/main/java/com/example/controllers:

```
package com.example.controllers;

import com.example.services.DefaultImageManipulationService;
import com.example.services.ImageManipulationService;
import com.example.entities.Classified;
import com.example.entities.Place;
import com.example.inbound.ClassifiedFormData;
import com.example.repositories.ClassifiedRepository;
import com.example.repositories.PlaceRepository;
import com.example.services.StorageService;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import java.awt.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
public class ClassifiedController {
    private final ClassifiedRepository classifiedRepository;
    private final PlaceRepository placeRepository;
    private final StorageService storageService;
    private final ImageManipulationService imageManipulationService;

    public ClassifiedController(ClassifiedRepository classifiedRepository,
                                PlaceRepository placeRepository,
                                StorageService storageService,
                                DefaultImageManipulationService imageManipulationService) {
        this.classifiedRepository = classifiedRepository;
        this.placeRepository = placeRepository;
        this.storageService = storageService;
        this.imageManipulationService = imageManipulationService;
    }

    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    @PostMapping(path = "/classifieds", consumes = { MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE })
    public void addClassified(@RequestPart(name="data") ClassifiedFormData classifiedFormData,
                              @RequestPart(name="images") MultipartFile[] images) {

        /* The end goal here is to get a classified and a place into the DB.
        If anything goes wrong, the transaction should be rolled back, and any saved images and thumbnails
        should be deleted. */
        List<String> filePaths = null;
        Path pathToImagesForThisClassified = null;
        String thumbnailPath = null;
        Path pathToThumbnailsForThisClassified = null;

        try {
            Classified classified = new Classified();
            classified.setSummary(classifiedFormData.getSummary());
            classified.setDescription(classifiedFormData.getDescription());
            classified.setPrice(classifiedFormData.getPrice());
            classified.setCurrency(classifiedFormData.getCurrency());
            classifiedRepository.save(classified);

            if (true) {
                throw new Exception("The saved Classified should be deleted because of the @Transactional annotation");
            }

            String idAsStr = String.valueOf(classified.getId());
            pathToImagesForThisClassified = Paths.get("images", idAsStr);
            filePaths = storageService.storeAll(pathToImagesForThisClassified, images);
            File thumbnail = imageManipulationService.resize(filePaths.get(classifiedFormData.getThumbnailIndex()),
                    new Dimension(255, 255));
            pathToThumbnailsForThisClassified = Paths.get("thumbnails", idAsStr);
            thumbnailPath = storageService.store(pathToThumbnailsForThisClassified, thumbnail);
            classified.setImagePaths(filePaths);
            classified.setThumbnailImagePath(thumbnailPath);
            classifiedRepository.save(classified);

            Place place = new Place(classified);
            place.setCountry(classifiedFormData.getCountry());
            place.setLabel(classifiedFormData.getLabel());
            place.setLatitude(Double.valueOf(classifiedFormData.getLat()));
            place.setLongitude(Double.valueOf(classifiedFormData.getLon()));
            placeRepository.save(place);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            storageService.deleteRecursively(pathToImagesForThisClassified);
            storageService.deleteRecursively(pathToThumbnailsForThisClassified);
        }
    }
}
```

ClassifiedControllerTest.java in src/test/java/com/example/controllers:

```
package com.example.controllers;

import com.example.entities.Classified;
import com.example.entities.Place;
import com.example.inbound.ClassifiedFormData;
import com.example.repositories.ClassifiedRepository;
import com.example.repositories.PlaceRepository;
import com.example.services.StorageService;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockMultipartFile;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestConstructor;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;

import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Optional;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertFalse;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@TestConstructor(autowireMode = TestConstructor.AutowireMode.ALL)
@DisplayName("ClassifiedController")
public class ClassifiedControllerTest {

    private final MockMvc mvc;
    private final ClassifiedRepository classifiedRepository;
    private final PlaceRepository placeRepository;
    private final StorageService storageService;

    public ClassifiedControllerTest(MockMvc mvc, ClassifiedRepository classifiedRepository,
                                    PlaceRepository placeRepository, StorageService storageService) {
        this.mvc = mvc;
        this.classifiedRepository = classifiedRepository;
        this.placeRepository = placeRepository;
        this.storageService = storageService;
    }

    @DisplayName("Any saved entities and files are deleted if an exception is encountered")
    @Test
    public void givenInvalidFormData_whenPosted_thenStatus400AndClean() throws Exception {
        // GIVEN
        ClassifiedFormData classifiedFormData = new ClassifiedFormData();
        classifiedFormData.setCountry("Spain");
        classifiedFormData.setCurrency("EUR");
        classifiedFormData.setSummary("Test");
        classifiedFormData.setDescription("Test");
        classifiedFormData.setLabel("Test");
        classifiedFormData.setPrice(32.45);
        classifiedFormData.setThumbnailIndex((byte)1);
        classifiedFormData.setLat("42.688630");
        classifiedFormData.setLon("-2.945620");

        MockMultipartFile classified = new MockMultipartFile("data", "", "application/json",
                ("{\"summary\":\"feefwfewfew\",\"description\":\"fewfewfewfewfwe\",\"price\":\"34\"," +
                        "\"currency\":\"CAD\",\"thumbnailIndex\":0,\"lat\":\"52.2460367\",\"lon\":\"0.7125173\"," +
                        "\"label\":\"Bury St Edmunds, Suffolk, East of England, England, IP33 1BZ, United Kingdom\"," +
                        "\"country\":\"United Kingdom\"}").getBytes());

        byte[] image1Bytes = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test_image.jpg").readAllBytes();
        byte[] image2Bytes = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test_image.jpg").readAllBytes();

        String image1Filename = "image1.jpg";
        String image2Filename = "image2.jpg";

        MockMultipartFile image1 =
                new MockMultipartFile("images", image1Filename,"image/jpeg", image1Bytes);
        MockMultipartFile image2 =
                new MockMultipartFile("images", image2Filename, "image/jpeg", image2Bytes);

        Path expectedImagePath = Paths.get("images", "5");
        Path expectedThumbnailPath = Paths.get("thumbnails", "5");

        // WHEN-THEN
        mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.multipart("/classifieds")
                .file(classified)
                .file(image1)
                .file(image2)
                .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());

        Optional<Classified> classifiedOptional = classifiedRepository.findById((long)5);
        assertFalse(classifiedOptional.isPresent()); // This is the assertion that is failing
        Optional<Place> placeOptional = placeRepository.findByClassifiedId(5);
        assertFalse(placeOptional.isPresent());

        Resource image1AsResource = storageService.loadAsResource(expectedImagePath, image1Filename);
        Resource image2AsResource = storageService.loadAsResource(expectedImagePath, image2Filename);
        Resource thumbnailAsResource = storageService.loadAsResource(expectedThumbnailPath, "thumbnail.jpg");

        assertFalse(image1AsResource.exists());
        assertFalse(image2AsResource.exists());
        assertFalse(thumbnailAsResource.exists());
    }
}
```

Test result:

```
java.lang.Exception: The saved Classified should be deleted because of the @Transactional annotation
    at com.example.controllers.ClassifiedController.addClassified(ClassifiedController.java:67)
    at com.example.controllers.ClassifiedController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7850f537.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
[some lines omitted for brevity]
expected: <false> but was: <true>
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <false> but was: <true>
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.fail(AssertionUtils.java:55)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertFalse.assertFalse(AssertFalse.java:40)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertFalse.assertFalse(AssertFalse.java:35)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertFalse(Assertions.java:210)
    at com.example.controllers.ClassifiedControllerTest.givenInvalidFormData_whenPosted_thenStatus400AndClean(ClassifiedControllerTest.java:148)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method never throws an exception, so there's no reason why Spring should rollback the transaction.

If it actually throws an exception (for example by adding `throw new RuntimeException(e);` at the end of the catch block), then Spring will rollback the transaction.

Answer (score 1):

You are catching the bubbled exception in catch block of addClassified(@RequestPart(name="data") method.

You have to throw the exception in the catch block or remove the catch block so that the interceptor of spring can know that an exception was thrown and rollback the transaction.

Answer (score 1):

The thrown exception

```
 if (true) {
  throw new Exception("The saved Classified should be deleted because of the *@Transactional* annotation");
 }
```

gets caught:

```
 } catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  // ...
 }
```

and does not leave the *addClassified* method, i.e. the exception will not be propagated. Therefore, Spring will not do anything.

At a high level, the @transactional annotation wrappes your code to something like:

```
UserTransaction utx = entityManager.getTransaction();

try {
 utx.begin();

 addClassified(); // your actual method invocation

 utx.commit();
} catch (Exception ex) {
 utx.rollback();
 throw ex;
}
```

**TL;DR**: You could remove the try-catch or (re-) throw a new exception inside your catch block.

Answer (score 0):

@Actully you should not handle exception due to this spring is not aware about exception so not able to rollback
And you have requirement that if exception occur then file must deleted. than you could like following.

```
public void addClassified(@RequestPart(name="data") ClassifiedFormData classifiedFormData,  @RequestPart(name="images") MultipartFile[] images) {

        //  to delete file  
        boolean flag = true;    

        try {
            Classified classified = new Classified();
            classified.setSummary(classifiedFormData.getSummary());
            classified.setDescription(classifiedFormData.getDescription());
            classified.setPrice(classifiedFormData.getPrice());
            classified.setCurrency(classifiedFormData.getCurrency());
            classifiedRepository.save(classified);

            if (true) {
                throw new Exception("The saved Classified should be deleted because of the @Transactional annotation");
            }

            String idAsStr = String.valueOf(classified.getId());
            pathToImagesForThisClassified = Paths.get("images", idAsStr);
            filePaths = storageService.storeAll(pathToImagesForThisClassified, images);
            File thumbnail = imageManipulationService.resize(filePaths.get(classifiedFormData.getThumbnailIndex()),
                    new Dimension(255, 255));
            pathToThumbnailsForThisClassified = Paths.get("thumbnails", idAsStr);
            thumbnailPath = storageService.store(pathToThumbnailsForThisClassified, thumbnail);
            classified.setImagePaths(filePaths);
            classified.setThumbnailImagePath(thumbnailPath);
            classifiedRepository.save(classified);

            Place place = new Place(classified);
            place.setCountry(classifiedFormData.getCountry());
            place.setLabel(classifiedFormData.getLabel());
            place.setLatitude(Double.valueOf(classifiedFormData.getLat()));
            place.setLongitude(Double.valueOf(classifiedFormData.getLon()));
            placeRepository.save(place);

            flag = false;
        } finally {

             if(flag){
                storageService.deleteRecursively(pathToImagesForThisClassified);
                storageService.deleteRecursively(pathToThumbnailsForThisClassified);
             }
        }
    }
```